# jquery .on("click", () =>{}) not working consistenly

Tags: jquery, clicklistener

I created several buttons dynamically. I added click handlers to them using $.on function in jquery. Sometimes the click is working and sometimes it doesn't register the click. I have to refresh again the page to check the click is working or not. Why is this happening?

```
function searchCompany() {
    $("#search-result").html('');
    let name = $("#company-name").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: `http://localhost:5000/manualharmonization/query?name=${name}`,
        success: function (data) {
            data.map((el, i) => {
                $("#search-result")
                    .append(`<tr class="list-item"><td>${el.applicant_original}</td>
                    <td><button class=${el.flag == 0 ? "button" : "submitted"} id="${i}"
                    type="button">Select</button></td>
                  </tr>`);

                res.push({
                    applicant_original: `${el.applicant_original}`,
                    flag: `${el.flag}`, name_friendly: `${el.name_friendly}`, appl_ref_no: `${el.appl_ref_no}`,
                    psn_id: `${el.psn_id}`, appl_key: `${el.appl_key}`
                })
            });
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e);
            alert(JSON.stringify(e));
        }
    });


    $("#search-result").on("click", "button", function () {
        if (res[`${event.srcElement.id}`].flag == 0) {
            $(`#${event.srcElement.id}`).removeClass("button");
            $(`#${event.srcElement.id}`).addClass("submitted");
            res[`${event.srcElement.id}`].flag = 1;
        } else {
            $(`#${event.srcElement.id}`).removeClass("submitted");
            $(`#${event.srcElement.id}`).addClass("button");
            res[`${event.srcElement.id}`].flag = 0;
        }
    })


}
```

Comment: please provide your code

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: Without clarification, it's hard to tell what your problem is. Hopefully, this will help you. Open your browser's console before you run the script (f12) so it will break at the `debugger;` statements and you can see the console.

Comment: Check if the element you have the event on is removed/added to the DOM. The event listener needs to stay on an element that is not dynamically changed. And if it is, you always need to reattach the event to said element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and i am sure this will definitely work for you.

```
$('body').on('click','.yourButtonClass',function(){
    alert('hi! I am clicked');
    });
```

Comment: @Kanhai try this one

Comment: Tried that told you function is not consistently  listening a click.

Comment: body and document both are giving an inconsistent result.